# URL Handling + MVC 4 + Jquery Ajax + IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've been developing an MVC 4 application that also includes Ajax via Jquery.
And I got a problem.

For example if I click a button, the onclick event fires a javascript method. This method is in a .js File.

That javascript method uses Ajax to call an `ActionResult` which receives some parameters (string, int) nothing special. So.. lets say my Action Result is in the "`Person`" `Controller` and that its name is "`Add`". So I want to add a Person.

My url property in my ajax call should be `"/Person/Add"` and my data should be something like:

```
var person = new Object();
person.name = "John";
person.id = 1;

data: person
```

This works without any problem when running the application with Visual Studio. But when I deploy it in IIS I get a 404 Error.

I've try this. I added a `<link>` `<link id="PersonAddURL" href="Url.Content("~/Person/Add") />` in the layout and then instead of using `url: "/Person/Add"` I changed it to `url: $("#PersonAddURL").attr("href")`.

This works, now, I dont think is a good way to solve it. There should be another one better. And still even if I managed to solve it, I would like someone to explain me the reason this is happening. I dont like the idea of having one link tag for each Url.

Thanks for the future answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I usually do is have the following global javascript variable in my ASP.NET MVC layout:

```
<script>var webroot = "@Url.Content("~/")";</script>
```

then from any JS file you can do the following:

```
$.post(webroot + "Person/Add", person, function(result){ ... });
```

just make sure you declare and initialize the **webroot**  variable before any AJAX calls.

If you are using namespaces in your javascript then you could change it to (assuming **app** namespace):

```
<script>app.webroot = "@Url.Content("~/")";</script>
```

and remove the global variable that makes developers uncomfortable.

Comment: But if i do this i'd get $.post("@Url.Content("~/")Person/Add", person, function(result){ ... }); or not ? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @NicolasGago if you are using the Razor View Engine the call to @Url.Content("~/") will expand the "~/" to the virtual path your webapp is running on or will just be "/" if running at the root. Just make sure you do so in your View (*.cshtml) file. I assume you are using Razor since you are in MVC4. If you are using WebForms View Engine then it can be changed to '<%= Url.Content("~/") %>'